# Libgit2 file contents from git_diff pointer

Tags: git, libgit2

I'm using libgit2 in my project and I want to get a list of the files as well as their content between two commits.

```
// ID of the selected trees from two commits & trees themselves
git_oid pre_tree_id, post_tree_id
git_tree *pre_tree, *post_tree;

// Here I get the trees
git_tree_lookup(&pre_tree, repo, &pre_tree_id);
git_tree_lookup(&post_tree, repo, &post_tree_id);

// Now I get differences between the trees
git_diff_tree_to_tree(&diff, repo, pre_tree, post_tree, NULL);
```

I get the git_diff object which I need to iterate over and recreate the file content in both commits.

Any ideas how I could do this?